# Virtual prototyping with Blender?

Tags: add-on, measurement

I'm currently designing furniture in Blender and was wondering if anyone has ever used Blender for virtual testing?  Specifically, if Blender has tools to ensure that parts will fit, structural testing, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Blender has a the Rigid Body World, there are various addons like [archimesh](https://github.com/Antonioya/blender/tree/master/archimesh) for aranging scene. You can measure everything in floating point precision. You should seek another software for structural testing though since most tools/addons in that direction aren't physically based and mainly a close approximation which looks good (e.g. the fracture addon).

Comment: Yes I love archimesh.  It's great for making scenes to put my pieces in and speeding up more mundane modeling like windows and doors.  But yes, apart from rigid bodies I think I will need to look to another program for structural testing.